# JQuery slideToggle not working for IE8 when using live events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've banged my head all over and none of the solutions seem to make this code work:

```
$(".showSomething").live('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $container = $(this).parent().parent().next("div");
            var title = $container.is(':visible') ? "Show" : "Hide" ;
            $container.slideToggle('slow');
            $(this).text(title);
        });
```

**When I click the `Show` link on the page, it does indeed change to `Hide` but that's it. The div that is supposed to toggle doesn't show and the link also gets locks into that `Hide` state.**

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="something" id="asdf">
    <div class="anotherthing">
        <span class="showSomething">Info</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="details">
    This Should Get Shown
</div>
```

**UPDATE**: I think there is some genuine issue with IE8 on this. I was able to get it working by switching to the following instead of "slideToggle"

```
var title = "";
            if( $container.is(':visible') )
            {
                title = "Show";
                $container.slideUp('slow');
            }
            else
            {
                title = "Hide";
                $container.slideDown('slow');
            }
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? What div is supposed to be shown?

Comment: Any error in your browser's JS console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with PIE.htc (css3pie.com). Avoid it like the plague because in addition to the problem I had above, if you apply it to one too many elements, your site will come to a crawl for IE7-8 users rendering it practically useless.

Answer (score 0):

I put this fiddle together, seems to work:  http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/XdXtr/

Given that, compare your structure to ensure the next div is similar to the example.

```
<div id='holder'>
    <div id='clicker' class="showSomething">click me</div>
</div>
<div id='hidyho'>it is me to hide or not</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're a `parent` out, I think.  Try:

```
var $container = $(this).parent().parent().next("div");
```

Comment: I had simplified the code for pasting here. My original code does indeed have the extra parent(). Updated the code here with it.